# Is this comment no longer needed?

Tags: discussion, comments

When looking how to do something I came across [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/508623/how-can-i-see-127-0-0-1-traffic-on-windows-using-wireshark/508624#508624):

> If you are trying to this on a Windows computer, unfortunately it is
>   not possible out of the box. You will need to install some additional
>   software that will capture data on the loopback interface. Follow the
>   guide at http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback.
>
> On a Linux computer, you will need to capture from the loopback
>   interface which is lo0 most of the time.

It had a comment with some helpful information:

> Actually, on Linux it's lo, with no 0 at the end. On other UNXes, you
>   would also capture from the loopback interface, and on most if not all
>   of those other UNXes it's lo0.

I proceeded to edit in the information from the comment, submitted the suggested edit (which was approved and is the current edit), and flagged the comment for deletion as I believe it is no longer required (I moved information from the comment into the question, except the part about Unix).

The "no longer needed" flag was subsequently declined. I then proceeded to raise a mod flag with an explanation of why I think the comment should be removed. That flag too was declined. After these two declines I raised *another* moderator flag asking for an explanation (as it would be helpful), which was also declined. All three flags were declined with no explanation of the reason for the decline.

I admit that the comment does contain information about Unix and this may have been the reason for the decline- I have submitted another suggested edit to move this information to the answer as.

The reason for this is:

- Comments are temporary and are not meant to be permanent
- [To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place](https://superuser.com/help/editing)
- Once this has been done, the comment should be removed as it no longer holds value (its information is in the answer)

Was I correct in requesting deletion of the comment?

I realise that one of these will apply:

- The comment still holds value as it contains information not present in the question, that I should've included in my earlier edit.
- The comment no longer holds value and should be deleted
- Both my edit and original flag was incorrect, and I am incorrect in my assumption that moving information from a comment to the answer merits deletion of the comment itself.
- The edit was correct but the original flag was incorrect as the comment still holds value

Comment: When I saw the flag I didn't realise there was an outstanding edit on the answer. I've approved the edit and removed the comment.

Comment: @cybermonkey - In the future come the chatroom and ask a moderator to explain the reason the flag was declined.  The backend of the mechanic you are using isn't very advanced.